# Disproving a function is a step function.

Tags: analysis

The function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) := 0$ if$ x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(p/q) : = \frac{1}{q} , q > 0, p,q$ coprime. How would you show that this is not a step function? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "step function"?

Comment: Is $f$ constant on any interval? Does $f$ take on only finitely many values?

Comment: @DavidMitra Ahh sorry, I thought of a simple function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). It is discontinuous at every rational number, and so is not continuous on any nontrivial interval -- which ought to contradict whatever definition of "step function" you're working with.